# Unregister SIP UAC message

Tags: sip, domain-registrar, pbx, domain-registration

I've looked so much on the internet, but I could not find a any SIP unregister example, and when I search RFC 3261,3665 the word does not even appear, perhaps I'm searching for the wrong phrase. I manage to understand the part of setting the expires to zero, but it still does not work and I could not find documentation about how a formal unregister should be.

Does anyone knows how to compose an Unregister SIP Request? or what should I search for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I asked this question after hours of searching, and finally I found something relevant:

I cloned my initial Registration request, took the contact headers, and added expires(0) values to them, and I added an expires=0 header, worked like a charm though I didn't get the contact headers back from the server with expires=0, but it did unregister me since I stoped getting 102 Options from it (it used to send 5 of these every few seconds).

So thanks anyway to who ever was trying to help!
Adam.

Answer (score 4):

An "[unregister](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-10.2.2)" is a REGISTER wherein you set the expires for one or more Contact URIs to 0. You may do so either with the Expires header - `Expires: 0` - which applies to all Contact URIs in the REGISTER, or with a parameter - `Contact: <sip:foo@bar>;expires=0` - which will only affect that URI's registration.

You may also unregister ALL contact URIs for your address-of-record by adding `Contact: *` and `Expires: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

A UA requests the immediate removal of a binding by specifying an expiration interval of "0" for that contact address in a REGISTER request. Check out [10.2.2 Removing Bindings in RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-10.2.2) for more detailed information.